# Is there a way to disable code coverage in PHPUnit for a single test?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Every time I run a single unit test in PHPUnit, a code coverage report is also generated. I have an older computer here at work, and if I could disable the code coverage when I don't need it, that would put less strain on my CPU.

Is there a way to disable the code coverage on a per-test basis? I couldn't find any command-line switch that would do it.

Comment: Have you tried doing it in the XML config?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

How about making a copy of your phpunit.xml, removing the `<logging>` stanza from it, then doing:

```
phpunit --configuration new.xml
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize it was that simple. I guess I can use a different configuration file when I'm running a single test vs. when I'm running the whole suite.

Comment: I ended up paring down my xml file to just <phpunit bootstrap="./TestHelper.php" colors="true"/>
... now it runs lightning fast. Wish I'd known this sooner!

Comment: I've got a shell script that runs PHPunit with a 'phpunit-FAST.xml' config - it doesn't do code coverage, and also exclude's some larger tests, marked with '@groupname' in the source. It runs most of my tests in 2 seconds. With coverage & all the other tests as well, 2.5minutes.

Comment: I commented out `<coverage />` and it worked. Removing `<logging />` didn't do anything noticeable.

Comment: @Jacob Heh yep, well this answer is 11 years old and the config format has changed a bit. Nowadays you can just put `--no-coverage` on the command line.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Thanks, just making a note for future readers... including myself :)

Answer (score 54):

Since this is one of google top results, I think it makes sense to point out that since version 4.8 PHPUnit now supports the `--no-coverage` option to override you xml configuration.

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/4.8.0/ChangeLog-4.8.md

Comment: No, this should not be the accepted answer. The question was for "a way to disable code coverage in PHPUnit for a single test" and not for disabling code coverage for a single run of all tests.

Comment: @SebastianBergmann The question is confusing, since it states that he wants to disable code coverage for a single test when he doesn't need it since he has an old computer. A command line is also mentioned.
I was not explicit but the idea is to use `--no-coverage` when running a single test (which I assumed the user was doing)

Comment: Thank you, @GonçaloQueirós, your reply was helpful :)

Answer (score 5):

You can annotate a test class or test method with `@coversNothing`. The test(s) then do not contribute to the code coverage report. However, code coverage data will still be collected (slowing down the execution). I plan to optimize this in the future.