# PHPUnit --no-coverage option to overwrite config file

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage

I use [PHPUnit](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/) to test my projects, using a `phpunit.xml.dist` config file.

The default configuration for all my projects is set to generate html code coverage reports.

Is there anyway I can run the `phpunit` command at a given time without generating the code coverage reports without having to change the config file?

This would be something like a `--no-coverage` option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to disable code coverage in PHPUnit for a single test?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789111/is-there-a-way-to-disable-code-coverage-in-phpunit-for-a-single-test)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't find anything  from the documentation to reference any sort of functionality that would provide the option to be a toggle.

You could point PHPunit to a second phpunit.xml that doesn't have the code coverage

You can see this very question being asked prior.

[Is there a way to disable code coverage in PHPUnit for a single test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789111/is-there-a-way-to-disable-code-coverage-in-phpunit-for-a-single-test)

Comment: Turns out this is really the only way to go. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

As noted by [Gonçalo Queirós](https://stackoverflow.com/users/282213/gon%C3%A7alo-queir%C3%B3s) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789111/is-there-a-way-to-disable-code-coverage-in-phpunit-for-a-single-test), the `--no-coverage` option is supported since version 4.8.